# Where Not Exists With One to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a hard time figuring out how to ask this question, so I'll just go straight to the example code. Let's say I have these tables:

```
create table Item
(
    ItemId int identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(256)
)

create table ItemSale
(
    ItemSaleId int identity(1,1),
    ItemId int,
    Price decimal,
    CategoryId tinyint
)
```

What I want to retrieve is the list of `ItemSale` records that are not in a given `CategoryId`. The complication, at least for me, is that if a record exists in `ItemSale` for a given `Item`, I do not want to see any records for that `Item`.

So if I have this data:

```
insert into Item(Name)
select N'Widget' union all
select N'Foo' union all 
select N'Buzz'

insert into ItemSale(ItemId, Price, CategoryId)
select 1, 9.95, 1  union all
select 1, 19.95, 2 union all
select 3, 99.99, 3
```

And the `CategoryId` I want to filter out is 1, then I don't want to see any records for `ItemId` 1 ("Widget"). So, with that sample data, I would only see the `ItemSale` record for `Item` with ID 3.

I know that my solution will most likely involve some sort of `NOT EXISTS` OR `LEFT JOIN` but I'm struggling with how to filter out all records instead of just the specific record that matches my criteria. What am I missing?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79c58

Comment: If the categoryId is in the ItemSale, you cannot find a item (on Item table) not in a category and not in ItemSale table. What you can do is find items (on Item table) that are not in ItemSale. Is that what you want?

Comment: @VitorTyburski I want to find Items in ItemSale that don't have a record with a particular CategoryId, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, and @GarethD answer is correct for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be over simplifying your problem, but I think this would work:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ItemSale i
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    ItemSale i2
            WHERE   i.ItemID = i2.ItemID
            AND     i2.CategoryID = 1
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79c58/8)**

Comment: It turns out you were not oversimplifying things, as this seems to be working great.